# Deleting in Laravel return 404 Not Found and not deleting

Tags: laravel

I am trying to delete a category in Laravel

In my controller I have this

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    $category->delete();

    return redirect()->back()
    ->with('success','Category deleted successfully');
}
```

I also tried to do this in my controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Category::destroy($id);
      return redirect()->back()
    ->with('success','Category deleted successfully');
}
```

In my view, I have this

```
<div class="card card-default">
<div class="card-header">Category</div>  
<div class="card-body">
<table class="table">
        <thead>
           <th>Name</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <tr>
                <td> {{ $category -> title }} </td>
                <td>  
                <form action="admin/category/{{category->id}}" method="POST">
                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">        
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
</table>
```

In my web.php, I have this

```
Route::delete('/admin/category/{category},'CategoriesController@destroy');
```

It keeps redirecting me to

> 404 Not Found

and it not deleting 
Please, I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: It's redirecting, is it redirecting correctly? Where is it redirecting to?

Comment: Looks like you have made a mistake in the view. Is your resource getting deleted?

Comment: It is not getting deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's because your form action is rendering wrong url which you don't have in your `web.php` file. the rendered url is something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/category/%7Bcategory-%3Eid%7D` because you are using `{category->id}` instead of category variable.

the form action should be like this

```
<form action="admin/category/{{$category->id}}" method="POST">
```

better approach would be using a named route

```
Route::delete('admin/category/{category}','CategoriesController@destroy')->name('category.destroy');
```

and the form action

```
<form action="{{ route('category.destroy',$category->id) }}" method="POST">
```